# MySQL InnoDB FOREIGN KEY ERROR

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the followiing tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Atletica` (
  `Universidade` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Logo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `GritoDeGuerra` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `EnderecoCEP` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EnderecoNumero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MedalhaOuro` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `MedalhaPrata` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `MedalhaBronze` int(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Endereco`
--

CREATE TABLE `Endereco` (
  `Rua` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Bairro` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CEP` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Cidade` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Estado` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Complemento` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `Atletica`
--
ALTER TABLE `Atletica`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Universidade`,`Nome`),
  ADD KEY `EnderecoCEP` (`EnderecoCEP`),
  ADD KEY `EnderecoNumero` (`EnderecoNumero`);

--
-- Indexes for table `Endereco`
--
ALTER TABLE `Endereco`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Numero`,`CEP`);
```

And I keep getting the error:

**Error creating foreign key on EnderecoCEP, EnderecoNumero (check data types)**

when I try to execute the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `Atletica` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`EnderecoCEP`, `EnderecoNumero`) 
REFERENCES `proj3`.`Endereco`(`CEP`, `Numero`) 
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Ive read tons of similar questions here but all of them the error was an obvious data type mismatch. I only have those two table on my database. Please help.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, when you create a foreign key with multiple columns, it should be in the same order ar the primary key in the referencing table.